# How do I see all the javascript functions and variables on a page in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I know you can click "inspect" and then click on "elements" to see the elements of the page, but it doesn't show any of the functions or variables of the page. Is there a way to see that? Thanks.

Comment: functions and variables that are defined in `<script>` tag inside the page can be seen in "inspect" and then "sources".

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the steps,

1. F12 open the debugging window
2. go to Sources tab near elements, it has CSS and JS
3. Ctl+Shift+F to search your code, it will go global search

Kindly refer for more details

- [Sources Tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/sources)
- [JS reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you type `debugger` into the console, you can see what all is visible on the global scope:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant see variables and functions because the browser only shows the current DOM [(Document Object Model)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

So basically what displayed in your browser is a html 'view' generated by the program on a server (e.g. a lot html elements are created through javascript). You only have direct access to the client(your computer) and the browser. Unless you have direct access or permission to the server (the machine where the actual file lives i.e. google cloud), you can only view the current html elements on your screen. it protects the program from public

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.dir(element);` instead of `console.log(element);`. It helped me a lot understanding the DOM and all the HTML-stuff. I hope, it will help you too...

Answer (score 0):

You could type `window` on the console and then they will show you all the functions and variables ..